# How to make TextEdit open with a blank file by default?

Tags: macos, textedit

In Lion, TextEdit used to open with a blank file by default. On Mountain Lion, it launches  with a file picker by default — either for choosing to store the file in iCloud or for opening a local file.

How can I make TextEdit launch with a blank file by default in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

If you don't want to disable syncing documents and data, run

```
defaults write -g NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false
```

and quit and reopen TextEdit to apply the changes.

To restore (thanks to comments run)

```
defaults delete -g NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile
```

To set this for TextEdit only (thanks to comment by gklka)

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false
```

Comment: This still works for macOS Monterey, (I only tested the last one from gklka)

Comment: The last one from gklka also still works in Ventura 13.2.1. Thank you!

Comment: @Lri Any idea how to do that for preview app ? I can’t toggle specific app from iCloud Drive sync options.

Answer (score 42):

System Preferences > iCloud > iCloud Drive ( Options ) > uncheck TextEdit.

Starting with macOS Ventura, it is System Settings > Internet Accounts > iCloud > iCloud Drive > Options > uncheck TextEdit.

Comment: Easiest answer!

Comment: Still working for me in 2022. Thanks!

Comment: The only thing I was missing from Windows was how quick the notepad was opening. Now it also is solved. :-)

Comment: I didn't need iCloud in TextEdit (for now) so this works perfectly. It's in System Settings > Internet Accounts for Ventura. Also, it took a while before the unchecking saved properly.

Comment: This one worked for me quickly and easily.  Thank you!!!!!!!

Comment: why does this work??

Comment: This will remove your files locally as I ´ve did in OSX 10.13.6!

Comment: Still working well, as of October 2023, on MacOS Sonoma 14.0.

Answer (score 12):

Go to System Preferences > iCloud > uncheck "Documents & Data" from the sync list.

Comment: Doing this will remove the possibility to save and sync documents and data from any application in OS X.

Comment: It's the only way - otherwise, it'll prompt whether you want to save a document to iCloud or locally. Remove iCloud from the mix, you get a blank document locally.

Comment: his will remove your files locally as I ´ve did in OSX 10.13.6!