# How to start TextEdit with a new document right away?

Tags: macos, textedit

Normally when I click on TextEdit or use Spotlight to open it, I'll have to click on "New Document". However, I notice some Mac start TextEdit with a new document right away. How did people do that?

I know [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61406/how-to-make-textedit-open-with-a-blank-file-by-default) but that requires either removing the functionality to sync text file with iCloud or using a terminal command. Is there an easier way?

Comment: It's not "right away" but in this situation for me ⌘ + N is simple enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AppleScript to launch TextEdit from Terminal with an new, empty document:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit"
   activate
   make document
end tell'
```

If you use it often you can turn it into a shell function by putting the following into the relevant startup file (`.bashrc` or `.zshrc`) of your shell:

```
function newtext() {
   osascript -e 'tell application "TextEdit"
   activate
   make document
end tell'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can have TextEdit always create an untitled document at launch (from https://git.herrbischoff.com/awesome-macos-command-line/about/#textedit):

```
defaults write com.apple.TextEdit NSShowAppCentricOpenPanelInsteadOfUntitledFile -bool false
```